# xml data into a dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I'm trying to get this xml info into a table.
I've tried reading the xml into a dataset...

```
         string myXMLfile = @"..\..\..\BR7.xml";

        //http://tatts.com/pagedata/racing/2011/10/5/BR7.xml
        //http://tatts.com/racing/2011/10/5/BR/7

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);


            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[i].TableName);
            }

            dgvRunner.DataSource = ds;
            dgvRunner.DataMember = "Runner";

            dgvWinOdds.DataSource = ds;
            dgvWinOdds.DataMember = "WinOdds";

            dgvPlaceOdds.DataSource = ds;
            dgvPlaceOdds.DataMember = "PlaceOdds";

            dgvFixedOdds.DataSource = ds;
            dgvFixedOdds.DataMember = "FixedOdds";
```

but I get four separate tables.  Runner, WinOdds, PlaceOdds, and fixedOdds
How do I get all the information for a Runner into a single table?

Here's some of the xml...

```
-<Runner RunnerNo="1" Rtng="93" LastResult="0X1" Form="W" Weight="57.0" Handicap="0" Barrier="10" RiderChanged="N" Rider="P SCHMIDT(A)" Scratched="N" RunnerName="PREACHER BOY">
<WinOdds CalcTime="2011-10-05T16:51:07" LastCalcTime="2011-10-05T16:46:32" Short="N" Lastodds="11.50" Odds="10.70"/>
<PlaceOdds Short="N" Lastodds="3.50" Odds="3.30"/>
-<FixedOdds RaceDayDate="2011-10-05T00:00:00" MeetingCode="BR" RaceNo="07" RunnerNo="01" LateScratching="0" Status="w" OfferName="PREACHER BOY" RetailPlaceOdds="3.3500" RetailWinOdds="12.0000" PlaceOdds="3.3500" WinOdds="12.0000" OfferId="981020"><Book SubEventId="863449" BookStatus="F"/> 
</FixedOdds>
</Runner>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the information about RunnerNo in every table (it is missing on WinOdd and PlaceOdds) so that you can relate your four datatables. You can define a the RunnerNo as Unique

After that you and use only one gridview and assing that relation between the four datatables as the gridview's DataMember.

here is a [sample](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=keuuy1&s=6) of how a relation  should look like

Answer (score 0):

I would propose an approach of moving all the attributes of the `Runner` children attributes to the `Runner` node attributes collection. This takes the following assumptions:

1. Each nested element in the `Runner` nodes has maximum 1 nested element inside it (i.e. there is only one `Book` element inside the `FixedOdds` element)
2. The attributes will be renamed by prefixing them with the name of their originating node (the `CalcTime` attribute in the `WinOdds` element will be copied in the `Runner` attribute's collection with the name `WinOddsCalcTime`)
3. You can keep or delete the children nodes (I chose to delete them in the code sample)

Here's the code:

```
    string myXMLfile = @"xml.xml";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(myXMLfile);

        var runners = doc.SelectNodes("/Runner");

        foreach (XmlNode runner in runners)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in runner.ChildNodes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < child.Attributes.Count; i++)
                {
                    var at =doc.CreateAttribute(child.Name + child.Attributes[i].Name);
                    at.Value=child.Attributes[i].Value;
                    runner.Attributes.Append(at);
                }
                if (child.Name == "FixedOdds")
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode book in child.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < book.Attributes.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var at = doc.CreateAttribute(book.Name + book.Attributes[i].Name);
                            at.Value = book.Attributes[i].Value;
                            runner.Attributes.Append(at);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // delete the attributes and the children nodes
                child.RemoveAll();
            }

            // delete the child noeds
            while (runner.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                runner.RemoveChild(runner.ChildNodes[0]);
            }
        }


        doc.Save("xml1.xml");

        ds.ReadXml("xml1.xml");

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[i].TableName);
        }

        dgvRunner.DataSource = ds;
        dgvRunner.DataMember = "Runner";

        //dgvWinOdds.DataSource = ds;
        //dgvWinOdds.DataMember = "WinOdds";

        //dgvPlaceOdds.DataSource = ds;
        //dgvPlaceOdds.DataMember = "PlaceOdds";

        //dgvFixedOdds.DataSource = ds;
        //dgvFixedOdds.DataMember = "FixedOdds";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
        }
    }
```